# Call jQuery method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript method which calls a jQuery function inside :

```
function diyalog()
{
   $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
}
```

And I get this error :

> TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

How can I call this jQuery method from my JavaScript method properly. Thanks.

Comment: Have you already added jQuery UI to your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is seems fine:

```
function diyalog(){
    $("#dialog-message").dialog();
}
diyalog();//calling
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vj4emho/)

You are missing jquery Ui. https://code.jquery.com/ui/. Add this in your html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to include jQuery and jQuery UI:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things: remove the $() wrapper around your jQuery call, as this is a closure (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that it used to invoke javascript on document load.

Also include jQuery.UI on your page, as the **dialog** plugin exists in this library.